How to read health connect data in background
I am developing an application to read the data from health connect. The app should read the data even if its in the background so that user won't have to reopen the app to sync the data from health connect.
In health connects documentation they have mentioned a permission to read data in background but I am unable to see the permission in the list in health connect and my app is unable to request or allow the permission.

Currently, only foreground tasks are supported, and background tasks will be supported starting from Android 15.
https://www.androidpolice.com/android-phones-health-hub-getting-key-upgrades-later-this-year/

Yes, you are right. But what about android devices below sdk 15? Is there a way? Can I use background workers or foreground services to achieve the result?
